# Using $timeout in service: this.func is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I've been trying to use promise to end user session after certain amount of time.

Problem is, whenever a function defined in service is called from the function triggered by $timeout, the function seems to be undefined. I think it's some kind of a scope issue, but I have not managed to fix this on my own.

```
app.service('sessionService', function($timeout) {
    var closeSession = function() {
        this.resetUserInfo()
        // maybe do other things as well
    }

    this.start = function() {
         console.log("start")
         promise = $timeout(closeSession, sessionLength)
    }

    this.resetUserInfo = function() {
        // reset session
    }
}
```

> Error: this.resetUserInfo is not a function

Things I have tried

- different ordering of functions
- `this.closeSession` instead of `var`
- `$timeout(function(){closeSession(this.resetUserInfo)}, sessionLength)` with proper modifications to closeSession

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the “this” keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: _this_ inside function, depends on how function calling. In your case _this_ not referse to service when function call as callback in $timeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note this assigned to that. So you are using the scope of the service instead of the scope of the method.

```
 app.service('sessionService', function($timeout) {
    var that = this;
    var closeSession = function() {
        that.resetUserInfo()
        // maybe do other things as well
    }

    this.start = function() {
         console.log("start")
         promise = $timeout(closeSession, sessionLength)
    }

    this.resetUserInfo = function() {
        // reset session
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked :)
Thanks. This now really seems like a duplicate, but I didn't know to search for right keywords.

Comment: No worries, you can try to read more on how the javascript scope works.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to make `resetUserInfo` a local function and then attach to it this later on. For example:

```
app.service('sessionService', function($timeout) {

    //private definition
    var resetUserInfo = function() {

    }

    var closeSession = function() {
        resetUserInfo(); //call the private version
    }

    this.start = function() {
         console.log("start")
         promise = $timeout(closeSession, sessionLength)
    }

    //now expose method as public here
    this.resetUserInfo = resetUserInfo;
```

}